# HDMI splitter (extend) was working for 6 months, but stopped working

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

Hoping this is the correct Stack site for this type of question. Having issues with my HDMI splitter no longer working at all, when it previously worked very well for about 6 months.

Tech specs: [Lenovo Thinkbook 14s Yoga](https://www.lenovo.com/ca/en/p/laptops/thinkbook/thinkbook-yoga/thinkbook-14s-yoga/xxtbxygi400)

- 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 2.40GHz
- Integrated Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics card
- Windows 10 64-bit

I had an HDMI splitter, [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07QKVY23Q/) specifically (2 HDMI to USB-C), that added 2 extend functions. My setup was this HDMI splitter was plugged into my laptop by USB-C and the laptop was extended twice to 2 external monitors. So I had 3 screens: laptop, monitor 1, monitor 2.

This was working for about 6 wonderful months, then one day, the both monitors just blacked out and turned back on, except only one turned back on. I unplugged the splitter and plugged it back in and then neither of them showed up at all. Now whenever I try to "Identify multiple displays" I get a notice that nothing is recognized when the splitter is plugged in. If I plug in monitor 1 or monitor 2 into my HDMI port, both monitors work.

[Screenshot of message I get when trying to identify monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkF20.png)

What I have tried so far:

1. Unplugging & plugging back in power + HDMI cables on both monitors.
2. Manually installing an older driver for my Display adaptor (didn't work)
3. Ordering a new HDMI splitter (still doesn't work)

Anything else I can try? Or a recommendation for a better HDMI splitter? Having the 3 screens really helps my workflow and 2 just doesn't cut it.

Thanks!

Comment: So now you have two black monitors when the splitter is plugged in or only one black monitor? If only one black monitor what happens when you swap the cables over in the splitter hdmi ports? does the problem move across to the other monitor? If yes, then you definitely have a fault with that splitter.. but after 6 months should still be covered by the manufacturer warranty. If both monitors black can you try using that splitter on a different machine? This will confirm if a compatibility issue has cropped up on your machine (since driver updates or program install whatever).

Comment: @Mastaxx Apologies, should have made my case more clear. I have 2 black monitors when the splitter is plugged in. But I also ordered a new splitter (same one) and it still doesn't work, still has 2 black monitors.

Comment: @Mastaxx I also tried plugging in each HDMI cord into my laptop to test the cords, and both cords and monitors are working. I believe the issue is either the splitter, or something with my drivers no longer wanting to recognize the splitter. I did rollback to a previous graphics card driver, but still had no success.